# Why high notes are too nasal and have to be pushed out hard through my nose

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I am a 22 year old male singer. At first I could not sing any note above a C4 (not including falsetto). But now after some practice I can go higher than C4, but the problem is that my voice becomes too nasal and strained after C4. It feels like I have to push the voice hard to bring out the voice. It doesn't seem like I'm hurting my voice but still the voice seems too forced and feels like it is being produced completely inside my nose. How can I fix this so I can sing those high notes properly and without feeling as if it is being pushed outside through my nose ?

Comment: A dupe of 'Voice - trouble with high notes'?